# How can I execute sibling scripts outside the directory?

Tags: bash, sh

```
$ ls -l
bin/
$ ls bin/
startup.sh shutdown.sh
```

I wrote a script named `restart.sh` inside the `bin/` looks like

```
#!/bin/sh
sh ./shutdown.sh
sh ./startup.sh
```

Now the `bin/` directory looks like this.

```
$ ls -l bin/
startup.sh shutdown.sh restart.sh
```

When I execute the `restart.sh` inside the `bin/` it works.

When I execute the `restart.sh` outside the `bin/` it doesn't.

```
$ ls
bin/
$ ./bin/restart.sh
sh: ./shutdown.sh: No such file or directory
sh: ./startup.sh: No such file or directory
$ cd bin
$ ./restart.sh
I'm happy...
```

How can I make this work?

Why down-votes? Is this normal?

**UPDATE**

I appreciate both comments and answers. I already know what `.` means in system. My apology must be given for making people confused. I accepted the answer because that is what exactly the context to be understood by my question. I should've asked some like *How can I make a shell script known to its path..?*

I give my answer for someone else. There are plenty of search results for detecting the actual position in shell scripts. I found one at [How a BASH script can find its own location](http://www.xensoft.com/content/how-bash-script-can-find-its-own-location).

```
#!/bin/sh
wd="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
echo $wd
sh $wd/shutdown.sh
sh $wd/startup.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `./scriptname.sh` the `./` says "only look in this folder for scriptname.sh".

And you are doing that, in a folder where scriptname.sh does not exist, so the shell returns "No such file or directory".

The fact that your restart.sh script is calling ./shutdown.sh on your behalf makes no difference, you're still in a folder where shutdown.sh doesn't exist, so the shell doesn't find it.

You either need to add your directory to the `$PATH` (an environment variable containing a list of folders the shell always searches, e.g. `export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/bin` (won't survive a reboot)) or you need to change the script to call `/home/me/bin/shutdown.sh` or you need the script to `cd /home/me/bin/` and call `./shutdown.sh`.